# How to convert words to leetspeak with Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a lists of words in a text file which I would like to translate into leetspeak on every word.

That is for example if I have the word `Hello`, this will change to `5E11O`.

In other words the program should be able to automatically replace every letter in a word.

Is this possible please? Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that actually says "SELLO", not "HELLO", j0.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you already know python?

Comment: I don' t know that much about python yet unfortunately since I am still a beginner but I'm willing to learn :)

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what the requirements for the leet speak translator are.  Can you be more specific to what you're trying to accomplish.  There are a number of ways to attack this problem, some which are simple but only have the power to attack a subset of possible translation problems, some that are more complicated.  If you want to put actual work into this problem I suggest reading the provided C code from this source: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/jbc/bork/src.zip  (Note: strictly for ideas on how to define your problem, not for implementation.)

Answer (score 5):

It completely depends on how you are defining leet.

If it is a simple 1:1 translation of each character, such as `H->5, e->E, l->1, l->1, o->0` in order to translate `Hello` -> `5E11O` it is not difficult. Use [string.maketrans](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) to define this character to character translation.

What is more difficult is if you wish to support more complete leet [orthographies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet#Orthography), such as `hacker-lingo` --> `l33tsp33k` which also involves shortening the number of characters.

There are a variety of leet source code efforts around. Try one. See if the shoe fits. I don't think leet has gone through ISO standardization yet...    ;-}

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do a series of one-for-one replacements in series. Note how the "whole word" transformations are applied before the letter-for-letter transformations.

```
replacements = ( ('hacker','haxor'), ('elite','eleet'), ('a','4'), ('e','3'),
                 ('l','1'), ('o','0'), ('t','+') )
my_string = "I am an elite hacker."
new_string = my_string
for old, new in replacements:
    new_string = new_string.replace(old, new)

print ( new_string )
```

gives:

```
I 4m 4n 3133+ h4x0r.
```

An interesting extension is to allow multiple choices for some replacements. For example, the character `l` can be rendered as either the digit `1` or the pipe symbol `|`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest is to make a characterset, and convert it

```
from utilitybelt import change_charset 

origspace = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
keyspace  = "abcd3fgh1jklmnopqr57uvwxyz"

print(change_charset("leetspeak",origspace, keyspace))

#l3375p3ak
```